# Issue on angular nested lazy routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

i m trying to implement nested child lazy load routing but i got some problem regarding routing.

here is my routing code:-
app.modules.ts looks like

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
                         {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
                         {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
          {path:'pages',loadChildren:'./pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
          {path:'**',component: NotFoundComponent}
                       ],{enableTracing:true})
```

pages.module.ts looks like:-

```
         RouterModule.forChild([
             { path:'', component:PagesComponent,
               children:[
                         {path:'',redirectTo:'user',pathMatch:'full'},
                         {path:'user',component:UserComponent },                                   


    {path:'forms',loadChildren:'./forms/forms.module#CustomFormsModule'}]
      }

])
```

forms.modules.ts:-

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {path:'',component:FormsComponent,
          children:[
            {path:'',redirectTo:'general',pathMatch:'full'},
            {path:'general',component:GeneralComponent},
            {path:'advance',component:AdvanceComponent}
        ] }
])
```

when I type path http://localhost:4200/pages - it redirects me to /pages/general
and even if i type pages/general it give me general component as there is no sure route defined in my routermodule.

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem?

Comment: It will navigate me to general -component even if I don't type full URL(page/forms/general) which I have specified in lazy load path. Also if I remove forms I.e (pages/general) it render general component instead it should give me not found page

Comment: Have a look at this stackblitz. Maybe you missed something https://angular-lazy-loading-n98uay.stackblitz.io/pages/user. When you navigate to /pages, it  shows the User component

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-lazy-route when i type /pages it should give me /pages/user instead it gives /pages/general and also i ve lazy route my general page as /pages/forms/general but general component in accessible through /pages/general .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing Lazy-loaded modules in your code

```
//pages.module.ts
import { CustomFormsModule } from './forms/forms.module';
//...
  imports: [
CommonModule,
CustomFormsModule, //<--Don't do that
```

When using lazy loaded modules, do not import them explicitely, otherwise the router gets confused

Here is the edited stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-lazy-route-kahove